# Grub video memory settings?

Tags: xorg, grub2

I have three monitors. Only two have a display. The solution that worked in the past was to increase the video memory in grub. I lost my old `grub.conf`file. So, instead of three displays, I only have two.

I have been searching and I cannot find the option to add to the vmlinux line to increase the memory reserved for video. I tried `vga=2400`, but that didn't work (note: I have 3 1280x1024 displays).

All I remember is that the last two times I had to do this, I searched for many days before finding it and then, magically, all three displays worked fine. Does anyone know what option that I'm missing might be?

Update: I have been investigating and I've found that the error is a core dump from xrdg, loaded from /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc:

```
cat /dev/null $XRESOURCES | xrdb -nocpp -merge -
```

If I comment that out, other files try to run xrdb, which core dump. So, apparently, it is xrdb which is trying to get more memory than is available. I'm trying to use that to figure out the kernel parameter for increasing the memory available.

Comment: Which video hardware/card is this (in the computer)?

Comment: There are two cards: Nvidia GTX 560 and Nvidia 8400GS. Two monitors are on the 560. One is on the 8400. I can get any two of the monitors working by commenting out one in the xorg.conf file. So, I know that the cards work, the configuration works, and the monitors work. However, any attempt to run all three causes only the first two to work. The third throws an error: "no matching config section". If I change the order of the screens listed, the last one is always the one that comes up with no matching config section.